# Unable to change the results of fields in a Word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a routine in Access to create a new Word Document based on existed template document. After saving the template to disc and opening it I want to change the results of certain fields in the Word document.

It seems to me that the way to do it is to assign to the text of the result a new value that is what I found on all references to changing the result. I am doing that and I use the update method but the new document still has the old results and I am unable to change that.

Anyone who can help?

```
Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim fieldLoop As Word.Field

  Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.application")
        For Each fieldLoop In appWord.ActiveDocument.Fields
            If InStr(1, fieldLoop.Code.Text, "Title", 1) Then
                fieldLoop.Result.Text = “newname”
            End If
            If InStr(1, fieldLoop.Code.Text, "DocCode", 1) Then
                fieldLoop.Result.Text = "newcode"
            End If
            If InStr(1, fieldLoop.Code.Text, "Category", 1) Then
                fieldLoop.Result.Text = “newcategory”
            End If
            If InStr(1, fieldLoop.Code.Text, "Author", 1) Then
                fieldLoop.Result.Text = "newauthor"
            End If
        Next fieldLoop
appWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify the type of field you are using but given your VBA code, your last command `appWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update` resets all fields to what the original field "code and type" would normally generate.

For example, if your field code was Info and the type was Author and your VBA routine altered the field Result to Albert Einstein from the original name of the document's author, then when you updated all fields again, the Result will revert to the original authors name.

The field data you are changing appears to be document properties and if you want to permanently alter those, you have to change the property value itself. There are two types of document properties, Built-in and Custom. You have to know what type of property you are modifying, built-in or custom. Below is sample code for permanently modifying document properties:

```
With ActiveDocument
    .BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title").Value = "My Document Title"
    .BuiltInDocumentProperties("Author").Value = "My Name"
    .BuiltInDocumentProperties("Category").Value = "New Category"
    .CustomDocumentProperties("DocCode").Value = "New DocCode"
End With
```

Comment: I tried various versions and had the update method included in each. Thought it was necessary but it seems that it was the cause of the problem. Removing it resolved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it does not seems to work the way I am trying to do. I want to change the original results which are stored in the field. As you stated "if your field code was Info and the type was Author and your VBA routine altered the field Result to Albert Einstein from the original name of the document's author" and I want that result to be permanent, i.e. removing the name of the original Author and replace it with the new name and to stay that way. What i want to do is changing the results which the "code and type" of the field would normally generate.

Comment: @user1045001, I have added an explanation of altering document properties.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that my understanding of the fields was a bit twisted. I used for example `field.Code.Text = "Title \* Caps  \* MERGEFORMAT " & Chr(34) & DocName & Chr(34)` and it changed the built-in values but not the custom ones. This was also the wrong approach!